# Pass RowID from application to a SQL Server stored procedure (or alternative)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method in my application which is passing `list<listitem>` into a stored procedure. I have created a table type data type to pass `list<listitem>`. Now I need to loop through in stored procedure to insert into another table. For that purpose I created row id column in the table type which is generated automatically.

Since the table type has 2 columns, it expects 2 parameters to pass from outside but I am generating it by identity column. Is there  any way to avoid so that I don't pass value form outside?

```
  public void test(List<string> listItem)            {
                 var table = new DataTable(); 
                 table.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(string));
                 foreach (string col1 in listItem) { table.Rows.Add(col1); }

                 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("TableTypeUpdateAnswers", conn);
                cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlParameter sqlParam = cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpUpdateAnswers",table);
                  sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured ;
                  sqlParam.TypeName = "dbo.AnswerTableType";

                conn.Open();
                try
                { }
              catch (Exception e)
                { }
  }
```

Here is the SQL to create table type :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AnswerTableType] AS TABLE(
    RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1),
    [col1] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

And here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestTableType]
    @TVPUPDATEANSWERS DBO.ANSWERTABLETYPE READONLY
AS
DECLARE
    @CURRENTROW INT,
         @VANSID int ,
    @ROWSTOPROCESS INT

BEGIN
    SET @CURRENTROW=0
    SELECT L.col1 FROM @TVPUPDATEANSWERS L;
    SET @ROWSTOPROCESS=@@ROWCOUNT
        WHILE @CURRENTROW<@ROWSTOPROCESS
            BEGIN
                SET @CURRENTROW=@CURRENTROW+1
                                     (SELECT @VANSID = col1
                 FROM @TVPUPDATEANSWERS 
                 WHERE ROWID=@CURRENTROW);

                //do something with table type datatype

                INSERT INTO DBO.table1(col3,col4) 
                VALUES(@VANSID ,@col4);
            END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may benefit from using this kind of approach - check it out and let me know... http://ilovedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/manage-multiple-updates-to-data-using-c.html